# linq2sql: Explicit construction of entity type '#some type#' in query is not allowed - also using join

Tags: linq-to-sql, inner-join

I am having a problem mapping. I was reading scottGU post of "data shaping features" - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx

but i have tried this

```
      IQueryable<AccessRights> accessRights = 
                            from t1 in this.db.AccessRights
                            join t2 in this.db.AccessRightsExtra
                            on t1.IdAccessRights equals t2.IdAccessRights 
                            where t2.IdUser== userId
                            select new AccessRights
                            {
                                IdAccessRights = t1.IdAccessRights,
                                Description= t2.Description
                            };
```

but produces this error "Explicit construction of entity type '#some type#' in query is not allowed"

As per scottgus post in link above i have also tried ( notice missing type after the the new in select)

```
     IQueryable<AccessRights> accessRights = 
                            from t1 in this.db.AccessRights
                            join t2 in this.db.AccessRightsExtra
                            on t1.IdAccessRights equals t2.IdAccessRights 
                            where t2.IdUser== userId
                            select new
                            {
                                IdAccessRights = t1.IdAccessRights,
                                Description= t2.Description
                            };
```

but this produces

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Really appreciate any insight that anyone has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
 IEnumerable<AccessRights> accessRights = 
    // This bit works in the database
    (from t1 in this.db.AccessRights
    join t2 in this.db.AccessRightsExtra
    on t1.IdAccessRights equals t2.IdAccessRights 
    where t2.IdUser== userId
    select new
    {
        IdAccessRights = t1.IdAccessRights,
        Description= t2.Description
    })
    .AsEnumerable() // From here on it's in-process
    .Select(x => new AccessRights
            {
                IdAccessRights = x.IdAccessRights,
                Description= x.Description
            });
```

Note that the result is `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IQueryable<T>`, but it will still be lazily evaluated. Is that going to cause a problem?

Alternatively, just use the anonymous type using an implicitly typed local variable:

```
var accessRights = from t1 in this.db.AccessRights
                   join t2 in this.db.AccessRightsExtra
                   on t1.IdAccessRights equals t2.IdAccessRights 
                   where t2.IdUser== userId
                   select new
                   {
                       IdAccessRights = t1.IdAccessRights,
                       Description= t2.Description
                   };
```

This will still be an `IQueryable<T>` but where `T` is an anonymous type. You won't be able to use this as an `IQueryable<AccessRights>` but if all you need is the `IdAccessRights` and `Description` properties, and you only need them in the same method, it might be good enough for you...

Comment: Thanks Jon! .. yep the second one works, problem is i need to cast it to IQueryable<AccessRights>  so i tried the following but test is null.  IQueryable<AccessRights> test = accessRights as IQueryable<AccessRights>;     

Is there a special way of casting it to my IQueryable<AccessRights>??   The column names in the anonymous type are exactly the same as the AccessRights?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, if you create a new derived class without the [Table]-Attribute like this:

```
public class AccessRightsLocal : AccessRights
{
}
```

Then you can create an instance of "AccessRightsLocal" inside the select. Cast the new instance to "AccessRights" and it will work!

```
IQueryable<AccessRights> accessRights = 
                    from t1 in this.db.AccessRights
                    join t2 in this.db.AccessRightsExtra
                    on t1.IdAccessRights equals t2.IdAccessRights 
                    where t2.IdUser== userId
                    select (AccessRights) new AccessRightsLocal
                    {
                        IdAccessRights = t1.IdAccessRights,
                        Description= t2.Description
                    };
```